# How to fix Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 262?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm opening the SQL Server Management Studio with **run as administrator**...

And there is no problem with Windows Authentication Connection.

I'm choosing "New Database" by right-click the Databases folder.

And giving name 'BTS' for the Database.

When i'm choosing OK, i get the error as,

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this blog post](http://menononnet.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-microsoft-sql-server-error-262/)

> To add a Windows user that has the login “machinename\Administrator”
>   to the sysadmin fixed server role
>
> 1. Log on to the computer using the credentials for the
>      machinename\Administrator account.
> 2. Click the Start button, point to All Programs, click Microsoft SQL
>      Server, and then click SQL Server Management Studio.
> 3. Connect to an instance of SQL Server.
> 4. Click Security, right-click Logins, and then click New Login.
> 5. In the Login name box, enter the user name.
> 6. In the Select a page pane, click Server Roles, select the sysadmin
>      check box, and then click OK.
>
> To add a Windows user that has the login “domainname \username” to the
>   sysadmin fixed server role
>
> 1. Log on to the computer using the credentials for the
>      domainname\username account.
> 2. Click the Start button, point to All Programs, click Microsoft SQL
>      Server, right-click SQL Server Management Studio, and then click Run
>      as administrator.
>
>    ps: “Run As Administrator” option elevates the user permissions In
>      the User Access Control dialog box, click Continue.
> 3. In SQL Server Management Studio, connect to an instance of SQL
>      Server.
> 4. Click Security, right-click Logins, and then click New Login.
> 5. In the Login name box, enter the user name.
> 6. In the Select a page pane, click Server Roles, select the sysadmin
>      check box, and then click OK.

Answer (score 5):

Click Start --> All Programs --> SQL Server Management Studio Express

SQL Server Management Studio Express---> Right Click--->Run as Administrator--> Click Yes

It works

Answer (score 0):

you are probably running more than one user profile on your laptop. While opening the program, right click and run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

try this:
SqlSever>>Security>>Logins>>BUILTIN\Users rightClick -->Properties
-->Server Roles
...select sysadimn

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).