# SQL Server 2012- Create Database permission denied in database master (Error 262)

Tags: sql-server, database, permissions

I want to create a new database on SQL Server 2012 using SQL Server Management studio. I ran SQL Server Management studio as administrator and logged in using Windows Authentication, but I still get this error:
Create Database permission denied in database master (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 262)

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

From this [blog](https://menononnet.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-microsoft-sql-server-error-262/) and also from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198458/how-to-fix-microsoft-sql-server-error-262)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run your SQL Server Management Studio Express.exe as an administrator. That's it.

I faced same problem and I tried to run my SQL Server Management Studio Express.exe as an administrator then it worked.